# Websockets Error： ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python-3.x, websocket

**I can‘t run this code on my PC,but it runs good on server**

```
import asyncio

import websockets


async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect('wss://fstream.binance.com/stream?streams=ethusdt@depth5@100ms') as websocket:
        while True:
            msg = await websocket.recv()
            print(msg)


asyncio.run(hello())
```

Comment: It would help if you provide information about the differences between the PC and the server, e.g. what OS are they running, python versions, etc. This information can help people pinpoint possible causes.

Comment: Add more context to the answer, you can always edit it. Some traces or debug with pdb could be useful

Answer (score 0):

ERROR HERE：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/johnxiong/PycharmProjects/mywork/tests.py", line 13, in <module>
    asyncio.run(hello())
  File "/home/johnxiong/anaconda3/envs/mywork/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/home/johnxiong/anaconda3/envs/mywork/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/johnxiong/PycharmProjects/mywork/tests.py", line 7, in hello
    async with websockets.connect('wss://fstream.binance.com/stream?streams=ethusdt@depth5@100ms') as websocket:
  File "/home/johnxiong/anaconda3/envs/mywork/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/py35/client.py", line 2, in __aenter__
    return await self
  File "/home/johnxiong/anaconda3/envs/mywork/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/py35/client.py", line 12, in __await_impl__
    transport, protocol = await self._creating_connection
  File "/home/johnxiong/anaconda3/envs/mywork/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1050, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/home/johnxiong/anaconda3/envs/mywork/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1080, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/home/johnxiong/anaconda3/envs/mywork/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 848, in _read_ready__data_received
    data = self._sock.recv(self.max_size)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: @mp3por `websockets` doesn't get to send any data, AFAIK, but the server closes connection anyways. So I think it's some kind of anti-ddos system and the issue should be IP address dependent. I have had the same problem with some proxies when parsing some bookmakers.